# How would the queueing delay in an LCFS queue change for different queue sizes?

Tags: queues, queueing-theory

Here we differentiate between the informative and non-informative packets. In FCFS, all packets are informative as they are sent in sequence, and so queueing delay rises with queue size. But i LCFS, once we sent a newer packet (newer in terms of packet generation times), all the packets that were generated after the newer packet are non-informative and we do not include their delay in our calculation. To give an example: 5 packets were generated in sequence, and gets enqueued in an LCFS queue. Packet 1 gets an empty queue and so it just passes through the queue without any queueing delay. When packet 1 was undergoing service, packets 2,3,4,5 arrive and due to LCFS policy, they are serviced in order of 5,4,3 and 2.

So the receiver received the packets in the following order: 1,5,4,3,2. Here only 1 and 5 are informative.

I haven't been able to find such analysis of queueing delay, also called age of information, for LCFS queues when queue sizes vary.